# Solving a differential equation without separating variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(t+1)\left(\frac{z'}{2}-1\right)=z$$

Can't find appropriate substitution to divide variables

Comment: the solution should be $$\left\{\left\{z(t)\to c_1+2 t\right\}\right\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(t+1)(z'-2)=2z\iff(t+1)z'-2z=2(t+1)$

Solve first the homegeneous equation $(t+1)z'-2z=0$ which gives $z=A(t+1)^2$

Apply constant variation : $z'=A'(t+1)^2+2A(t+1)$

Reporting in equation gives : $(t+1)^3A'=2(t+1)$ or $A'=\frac{2}{(t+1)^2}$

$A=B-\frac{2}{t+1}$

> Finally $z=B(t+1)^2-2(t+1)$

An alternate method, let's have $z=(t+1)u\quad$ this is motivated by the fact that we have $z/(t+1)$ on rhs or similarly that $z(-1)=0$ in original equation.

$z'=u+(t+1)u'$

reporting in equation : $(t+1)u+(t+1)^2u'-2(t+1)u=2(t+1)$

gives $(t+1)u'-u=2$.

A particular solution is $u_0=-2$ and solution of homogeneous equation is $u_h=C(t+1)$. General solution is $u=u_h+u_0$.

> Finally $z=(t+1)[C(t+1)-2]$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(t+1)\left(\frac{z'}{2}-1\right)=z$$

$$ \left(\frac{z'}{2} -1\right) = \frac{z}{t+1} $$

$$ z'=\frac{2z}{t+1}+2 $$

$$ z' + \left(\frac{-2}{t+1} \right) \cdot z =2$$

Integrating Factor $\implies \exp\left({\int \frac{-2}{t+1}dt}\right)=e^{-2\ln|t+1|}=\frac{1}{(t+1)^2}$ and multiplying through

$$ \frac{1}{(t+1)^2}\cdot z' + \frac{1}{(t+1)^2} \cdot \left(\frac{-2}{t+1} \right) \cdot z=\frac{2}{(t+1)^2}. $$

$$ \left( \frac{1}{(t+1)^2}\cdot z \right)'=\int \frac{2}{(t+1)^2} dt. $$

$$ \frac{1}{(t+1)^2}\cdot z  =\frac{-2}{t+1}+C$$

$$ \implies z= -2(t+1)+C(t+1)^2$$